# SPA re-login when session expires

Tags: angularjs, session, single-page-application

I'm building a single-page application with AngularJS. I'm considering 2 approaches to handling  a long idle period wherein the server-side session expires.

### Approach A: Detect during AJAX, Relogin, Resend

- user loads app initially and signs in
- user uses app for a while then goes idle leaving the app open
- server side session expires
- user resumes using the app
- when attempting to save data, an angular http interceptor detects a 401 status code response, shows a sign in modal dialog, and if the user correctly authenticates (thus starting a new server side session), re-submits the change to the server

My take on this is it is technically possible, but the UX might be a bit jarring and the implementation could get complicated since there might be many types of AJAX requests that trigger the 401 response (clicking a link, editing a field, etc)

### Approach B: Track idle time on client and prompt to relogin

- user loads app initially and signs in
- user uses app for a while then goes idle leaving the app open
- on each server response, the browser code starts an idle timer
- when there has been no server interaction for longer than the session expiration period, the browser preemptively shows a sign in modal dialog
- the user comes back, sees the dialog, and can sign in before continuing to use the app.

I think this approach is perhaps a better UX and is also simpler to implement since there's no retry logic.

---

**Do either of these strike you as solid? Got a better approach?**

Answer (score 0):

Well each one of them have their pro and cons but I use a hybrid approach to get the benefits of both approaches and also ditch the cons. The core of my approach is A i.e. having a filter in server side to update the session info (expiration, validity) for each request, but client also sends keepalive requests periodically based on the user interactions with UI. Each keep alive gets a response back from server that indicates that session is still valid (not invalidated by signing out from another tab or by SSO). The things you need to remember:

1. Approach 1 by itself is not sufficient since users consider reading text and scrolling and clicking around activity. So if you have client side functionality hooked into clicking (e.g. showing popups) that is not sending Ajax calls to server then user will be signed out even though they keep clicking on that button.
2. Approach 2 by itself also is not sufficient since you only rely on user activity on the current user tab (unless you use browser storage) and not on server data. The issues raised by this are a) user signs out in another tab but is still logged in in another tab b) in many secure cases you will need to embed your application using single sign on into third party apps, then effectively you need to be signed on as long as user is being active in another application.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Approach A.
But a more elegant way is to use `$httpProvider.interceptors`.

Right after Angular App is initiated, config your app like this:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 440) {//I prefer to use 440 to indicate the user is timeout.
                    //window.location.href = "/login"; redirect to your login page
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

By doing this, a redirect method can be injected into **$http**'s method. Any time if server sends back **`440`** code, this method would be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

After giving this problem a whirl for a while, I went about it as follows and seems more robust than each of the above methods alone.

Basically when the user leaves the tab/page, you start a timer and upon their return compute the inactive time. If it's more than a certain threshold (no need to be equivalent to your session lifetime and a sensible assumption like 10 mins would be good enough) you make a call to the server to see if the session is still alive, if not invalidate the session client side.

This differs from method 2 in that you don't start the timer on each server response, rather each time user (i.e. given a session is started client side) leaves the page/tab and as such doesn't have the associated cons. Goes without saying I'm using local storage to keep tabs in sync and not lose hold of the session upon a refresh.